# Multiple string interpolation in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to build an SQL query that involves two separate insertions of the same string, which itself is constructed by joining a list (terms) with commas. I'm doing this as follows:

```
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(terms))
sql = """
SELECT i.id, i.title, i.description, MATCH (i.title, i.description) AGAINST (%s IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
FROM items i
WHERE MATCH (i.title, i.description) AGAINST (%s IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score""" % format_strings, (terms, terms)
```

The result is `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

This works with just the one use of terms, but not a second. I'm very new to Python, so this is probably something pretty straightforward. Any help much appreciated!

Edit: terms comes from running .split() on a string including spaces, so `('apples', 'oranges')` would be an example value.

**Update**:

The following results in an SQL error, but it does look rather like the strings aren't being substituted (an %s appears in the SQL):

```
terms = term.split()
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(terms))
sql = """SELECT i.id, i.title, i.description, MATCH (i.title, i.description) AGAINST (%s IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
FROM items i
WHERE MATCH (i.title, i.description) AGAINST (%s IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)""" % (format_strings, (terms, terms))
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Output:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score\tFROM items i\tWHERE MATCH (i.title, i.descr' at line 1")
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what `terms` looks like, and an example of what `sql` would look like when properly formatted? Because without this, we have to be parsing your SQL and trying to guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure this will lead to SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass two instances of `format_strings` when formatting the query, or, better yet, use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and reference the argument twice:

```
sql = """
SELECT i.id, i.title, i.description, MATCH (i.title, i.description)
  AGAINST ({0} IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
FROM items i
WHERE MATCH (i.title, i.description) AGAINST ({0} IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
  AS score""".format(format_strings)
```

Then pass the parameters to `cursor.execute()`:

```
cursor.execute(sql, terms*2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your sql as follows:

```
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(terms))
sql = """SELECT i.id, i.title, i.description, MATCH (i.title, i.description) AGAINST (%s IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score FROM items i WHERE MATCH (i.title, i.description) AGAINST (%s IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score""" % (format_strings, format_strings)
#Execute the sql in your database cursor
db_cursor.execute(sql,[terms,terms])
```